# Get default value of column in Slick?

Tags: scala, default, slick

Is there an easy way to do this?  I got lost wading around in the source trying to find some code that would do this.

Answer (score 3):

Slick's table component provides additional column options. This is accesable via an object O.

So to get a default value specified for the column, you could do something like this:

```
def mycolumn = column[String](
       "MYCOLUMNNAME",
       O.DBType("VARCHAR"),
       O.Default("Let's eat icecream"))
```

Comment: This is how you _set_ the default value, not how you get it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Given a table

```
 object Users extends Table[(Int, String)]("users") {
   def id = column[Int]("id")
   def name = column[String]("name")
 }
```

You can get the default value for the id column like so:

```
 val driver: BasicProfile = scala.slick.driver.H2Driver //use the one appropriate to you

 val defaultValue: Int = Users.id.typeMapper(driver).zero
```

Citing the documentation:

- [TypeMapper](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/api/#scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper): "TypeMapper object represents a Scala type that can be used as a column type in the database".
- typeMapper(driver) produces a [TypeMapperDelegate](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/api/#scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapperDelegate) which is a type mapper specific to the driver being used
- the `zero` method on the `TypeMapperDelegate` gives "a zero value for the type".

I haven't tested if this returns the default value you set for a column when you define the table or just a general zero-value specific to the type, but not to the table.

Answer (score 0):

The default value can be extracted as follows:

```
import slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile.api._
import slick.relational.RelationalProfile

def getDefaultValue(fieldName: String, table: Table[_]) = {
  table.create_*.toSeq.find(_.name == fieldName)
    .flatMap(_.options.collectFirst {
      case RelationalProfile.ColumnOption.Default(defaultValue) =>
        defaultValue }).orNull
}
```